# Sqlalchemy event `append` listener causes UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
 class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Paper(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'papers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reviewers = db.relationship('User', secondary=paper_reviewer,
                                backref=db.backref('papers_reviewed',
                                                   lazy='dynamic'),
                                lazy='dynamic')

paper_reviewer = db.Table('paper_reviewer',
                          db.Column('user_id', db.Integer,
                                    db.ForeignKey('users.id'),
                                    primary_key=True),
                          db.Column('paper_id', db.Integer,
                                    db.ForeignKey('papers.id'),
                                    primary_key=True)
                          )

@event.listens_for(Paper.reviewers, 'append')
def paper_reviewers_append(target, value, initiator):
    # db operation on other tables
    # target is paper obj
    print target.reviewers.all() # or other operation


paper.reviewers.append(usr)
db.session.add(paper)
db.session.commit()
```

The listener is fired before the execution of `paper.reviewers.append(usr)`. The execution of append makes two insertions into paper_reviewer table. The second one causes `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed`.

I tried different operations in the listener. If the operation triggered any query, the IntegrityError would be caused while the commit() was executed.

Comment: You'll have to provide an [mvce]. `# db operation on other tables` is not enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @univerio I already mentioned in the description: If the operation triggered any query, the IntegrityError would be caused while the commit() was executed. It doesn't matter which table is called.

Comment: I understand that you've described what you're doing. What I'm asking for is a concrete example that I can run. If it's any query, then put in any query you want. Think about the steps I need to take to reproduce your problem; I need to add the missing `User` model, then interpret what you mean by `db operation on other tables`, then finally, if everything works fine, second guess whether I've interpreted `db operation on other tables` correctly. Providing a complete example will eliminate other variables. Sorry I messed up the link earlier: [mcve]

Comment: @univerio Thx for the reply. I didn't expect you would try to run the code. Similar issues have been posted on google group. Solution is "you likely have autoflush occurring within your listener so use "with 
session.no_autoflush": 
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=autocommit#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.no_autoflush "

Comment: A generic "disable autoflush" seems like bad advice. It'd help a lot more to understand what autoflush actually is and why it takes place (queries might observe stale state, if session has modifications), in relation to what is actually being done, which is still not shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote a solution from a google group member
"you likely have autoflush occurring within your listener so use "with 
session.no_autoflush": 
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=autocommit#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.no_autoflush"

```
@event.listens_for(Paper.reviewers, 'append')
def paper_reviewers_append(target, value, initiator):
"""Update review preference."""
with db.session.no_autoflush:
    # db operation on other tables
    pass
```